# Prove that $\arccos(\cos(x, y))$ is a metric

Tags: trigonometry, metric-spaces, data-mining

I'm taking a data mining course in uni, and the professor asked us to prove that $\arccos(\cos(x, y))$ is a metric. I've never seen such a notation, having two numbers inside cosine function. Does anyone have a clue to what does it mean?

Comment: What is $\cos(x,y)$? The Cosine I'm used to takes only one argument.

Comment: Could this mean something like $d(x,y)=|\arccos (\cos x ) - \arccos (\cos y)|$?

Comment: If that is the case, I presume it would go something like this, since arccos and cos are inverse, d(x,y) = |x + 2kπ - (y + 2kπ)| = |x - y|, and since it is an absolute value, it is always greater than(or equal to) zero, symmetric, and, regarding triangle ineqaulity: |x - z| <= |x -y| + |x - z|

Comment: Possible interpretation $\cos(x,y)=\cos\angle(x,y)=\langle x,y\rangle/\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle\langle y,y\rangle}$, but if so that is very bad notation.

Comment: @BenjaminWang the key problem there is that this isn’t a metric. $d(x,y)=0$ for some $x\neq y.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews If restricted on the unit sphere, this is just the length of the spherical arc from $x$ to $y$ and defines a suitable metric.

Comment: @Didier hat are $x,y$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Two points on the unit sphere, when considered as unit vectors in the euclidean space: indeed, the metric on the sphere reduces to the angle between them (recall the definition of radians), and the formula given above is just $\cos^{-1} (\cos (\text{angle}))$

Comment: @Didier does $\cos x$ mean something when $x$ is on the unit sphere?

Comment: There is an angular metric on the unit sphere, but it is not defined as $|\arccos(\cos x)-\arccos(\cos y)|,$ it is defined as $\arccos(x\cdot y).$ @Didier

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Not $\cos x$ but $\cos(x\cdot y)$ (their dot product). I think we're talking about the same object. I guess OP made a confusion bewteen $(x,y)$ and $(x\cdot y)$

Comment: @Didier but you replied to me, and I replied to Benjamin Wong, who gave a very specific interpretation, to which I was replying. I was  pointing out that interpretation was not a metric.

Comment: It's the cosine similarity function. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cosine-similarity/